# Accessing through VPN, which internet connection would be used

Tags: internet, vpn

I've a data card which has a limit of 2 GB up/download traffic per month. I've an office internet line which has an unlimited up/download.

I've successfully connected to VPN using my data card and by changing certain configurations like DNS etc., have also been able to use my office line for internet (verified by doing a IP check - returns the static IP of our office).

Now to my question - is it just a NAT which is happening or am I actually using my office line  for all communication. Which one would reflect the usage/trace. The data card usage log at this moment does not reflect any usage (which is confusing since the VPN is over the data card connection).

Further more (theoretically), would the net be any faster if my office line is let us say 8Mbps and the data card is 512kbps by doing this as against directly connecting the internet using the data card.

Answer (score 1):

All traffic to the VPN still goes through your data card and still uses up your data allowance. Browsing the internet via the VPN can only SLOW the browsing and can never speed it up. Essentially you're making the journey longer and adding a huge amount of latency to the connection. The fact that the traffic is not showing up in your datacard's utility software is most likely either a bug, or perhaps it can't "see" the traffic inside the encrypted VPN.

If you want to check which is faster, simply run a speed test (in both configurations) using any popular broadband speed testing website.

Answer (score 0):

You are using your office line for communication with Internet. This is standard configuration (though it can be changed) and the reason is security.

When you connect by VPN your PC becomes part of company's local network. When you open your local internet connection while having VPN connection active, you are in fact creating back door to your company's network, which bypasses all security efforts made by administrator.

If your PC gets infected or compromised, all bad programs and people will be able to access network resources in your company without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

your vpn connection is through your data card and so your local Internet bandwidth would be used for Internet, for browsing as well as your company's network through vpn